# "Beim Essen gehen/Essengehen/essen gehen...": Groß- oder Klein-, Zusammen- oder Getrenntschreibung?

Tags: spelling, capitalization, nominalization

Jemand hat mich letztens gefragt, wie die Groß- und Kleinschreibungsregeln für den Satzanfang in *"**Beim Essen gehen** habe ich einen Freund getroffen."* aussehen. Meinen Kenntnissen zufolge (und ich bin weder ein Linguist noch ein Deutschlehrer) versteckt sich in "Beim" der Artikel "dem", weshalb "Essen gehen" ein substantiviertes Verb ist, also effektiv ein Nomen, und daher groß geschrieben werden muss. Aber wie sieht es bei "gehen" aus? Laut [Korrekturen.de](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/essengehen.shtml) darf ich "Essen gehen" auch nicht zusammenschreiben, in welchen Fall sich mir die Frage gar nicht erst stellte. Aber bei [Korrekturen.de](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/essengehen.shtml) ist "essen gehen" in der Funktion eines Verbes und nicht in der Funktion eines Nomens, also weiß ich nicht, ob die Regel auf [Korrekturen.de](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/essengehen.shtml) überhaupt auf meinen Fall anwendbar ist.

Hier sind also meine konkreten Fragen:

1. Wird "Essen gehen" (im Beispielsatz oben) zusammen, auseinander, oder mit Bindestrich geschrieben?
2. Wird "Essen" groß oder klein geschrieben?
3. Wird "gehen" groß oder klein geschrieben? [nur falls "Essen gehen" nicht zusammen geschrieben wird]

Mich interessieren in erster Linie diejenigen Antworten die konform mit den Regeln der Grammatik sind, und nicht so sehr die Antworten, die lediglich akzeptabel sind (wie etwa "Es ergibt Sinn" richtig und "Es macht Sinn" (nur) akzeptabel ist).

Comment: Auf korrekturen.de steht doch: "Abzugrenzen ist jedoch die Substantivierung: »Man kann sich das Essengehen in Restaurants kaum noch leisten.«"

Comment: @DonHolgo Oh, das hatte ich nicht gelesen. Da hätte ich mir ja schon einiges Kopfzerbrechen im voraus sparen können :D Aber mit der Antwort von hier habe ich sogar eine Referenz zu den Regeln im Duden :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Duden-Regelwerk sagt dazu, bei der Substantivierung solcher Wortgruppen mit einem Infinitiv schreibt man zusammen.

Also:

> Wir waren essen gehen, als ich einen Freund traf.

Aber bei Substantivierung:

> Beim Essengehen habe ich einen Freund getroffen.

Wenn es noch mehr Bestandteile sind und es unübersichtlich wird, nimmt man Bindestriche, wobei der Anfang und der Infinitiv groß geschrieben werden:

> Es ist zum Aus-der-Haut-Fahren.

https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#D47 (in der Anmerkung am Ende)

https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#D55

https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich#D27

Comment: _Wir waren essen gehen_ würde ich allerdings nicht als standardsprachlich durchgehen lassen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin auch kein Linguist, aber mit dieser Fragestellung habe ich in der Schule mal eine Deutschreferendarin herausgefordert.

Bei einer Substantivierung von zusammengesetzten Verben wird das Verb als ein Wort und groß geschrieben.
Je nach Verb wird das Wort zusammengezogen, z.B: `Vor dem Schlafengehen` oder mit Bindestrichen versehen, z.B: `Zu-spät-Kommen`.

Da nirgends genau definiert ist, welche Wörter mit Bindestrichen geschrieben werden und welche zusammengezogen werden, sollte hier beides erlaubt sein.

Edit: tofro hat darauf hingewiesen, dass die Bindestrichschreibweise nur bei mehr als zwei Bestandteilen erlaubt ist.
Damit wäre nur `Essengehen` erlaubt und `Essen-gehen` falsch.

Comment: Die Bindestrichschreibweise ist zwar erlaubt, aber nur dann, wenn das substantivierte Verb aus mehr als zwei Bestandteilen besteht, also **nicht** "vor dem Schlafen-gehen"

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis, ergänze ich direkt. Ich habe [hier](http://www.neue-rechtschreibung.net/2009/08/11/knifflige-substantivierungen-verben-in-zusammensetzungen/) noch einen passenden Artikel dazu gefunden. _Das Sicherverlieben_ sieht aber trotzdem irgendwie falsch aus.

Answer (score 2):

Der Rechtschreibrat sagt dazu ganz lapidar:

> mehrteilige Substantivierungen schreibt man zusammen

[Rechtschreibregeln §37/2](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6155)

und nennt folgende Beispiele:

> das Holzholen, das Inkrafttreten; der Kehraus, das Stelldichein, das Vergissmeinnicht